# Allow LAN access between devices on two different LANs

Tags: networking, router, lan, switch, wan

My current setup:

- 4G WiFi modem/router with Ethernet ports

  - Media devices (Chromecast, phones etc)
- ADSL modem into WiFi/Ethernet router

  - Latency sensitive devices (PC/game consoles etc)

Reason for my current setup is speed vs latency

My goal:

- Allow a device connected to 4G to access a device using ADSL without using the internet. i.e. over LAN.

Currently nothing exists between the two routers. I am trying to find out if I can connect then via Ethernet directly with some settings tweaking, or if I will need a switch (and which type of switch) between the two. I don't mind setting custom DNS or whatever else is required on the devices, although it may not be possible on some of the 4G connected ones.

Comment: This question has been asked in various variants. The simplest way is to set up static routes on both routers for the other router. If the manufactures firmware doesn't allow that, you need custom firmware (e.g. OpenWRT), or other approaches.

Comment: Do you have an example link? I searched multiple times before and after your comment with no success.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to achieve this without having to mess with routing would require the following setup (assuming both your routers are doing NAT and you have a private address space):

- 4g router with LAN network `192.168.0.0/23` (DHCP pool `192.168.0.10-110`)
- ADSL router with LAN network `192.168.1.0/23` (DHCP pool `192.168.1.10-110`). Set this router's LAN IP address to static in the higher range, for example `192.168.1.1`.
- pass one ethernet cable between both routers

This effectively creates a "giant" /23 LAN address space shared among both routers (joined at the layer2 level).

This setup is a but messy with regards to DHCP, since you will have two servers in your now-joined network, you have a few choices:

1. only one router has DHCP server enabled, you must pick which will give you internet access
2. both routers have DHCP server enabled. Problem: this means you won't control which router each device uses to reach the internet, since it will depend on how fast each router responds to DHCP Discover requests. It will usually be the router to which the device is directly connected, but it's not clean.
3. both routers have DHCP server enabled, and you block LAN DHCP Discover requests from leaving the routers. That way, clients plugged into your 4G router will only get IP addresses from its pool, and the same for the ADSL router.

The second option is the easiest to achieve while keeping use of both internet connections, and it should never happen that a device plugged into your ADSL router gets an IP from the 4G router and vice versa.

Note: I assume wired (ethernet) devices only, you didn't specify if your routers have separate SSIDs. If they do, the same effect should be achieved.

Comment: I like this suggestion, thank you. I read a few threads that highly discouraged 2 DHCP (which I understand the reasons for). The routers have separate SSIDs, all ADSL router connections are Ethernet, all 4G router connections are wireless.  If I disable DHCP on the ADSL router and set the connected devices to static IP in the ADSL router range would that make them use the ADSL connection?

Comment: Which internet connection your devices will use will depend on which default gateway (route) they use. If you are setting static IP addresses for the devices connected to the ADSL router, then you must also set the default gateway as that router's LAN address.

Comment: Excellent, thank you I will try that by setting all the media devices to auto and only enabling DHCP on the 4g wifi modem/router.
Then I will set all ADSL devices to static IP (ADSL router range) and set their gateway to the ADSL router IP